# Using angularjs-dropdown-multiselect for dropdownwith checkbox, how to disable particular options using their id's

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

Here is the code where I have used the plugin to display options with checkbox in angular.I need to disable particular/set of options based on a condition. the ng-disable does not seem to help. Jquery needs to identify each li or option using id's.

```
<div  ng-if="tab===1" 
      class="col-md-3 padd0LeftRight marTop5 width150" 
      ng-dropdown-multiselect="" 
      options="severities"  
      selected-model="$parent.severityModel" checkboxes="true" 
      extra-settings="severitySettings" 
      translation-texts="SeverityText"></div>
```

<kbd>Controller:</kbd>

```
$scope.severityModel =[];
$scope.severitySettings = { 
    showCheckAll: false,
    showUncheckAll:false,
    externalIdProp: ''
};
$scope.SeverityText = {
    buttonDefaultText:"Severity "
};

{label: $scope.resource['casepage.filter.ciscopending.internal'], 
  name:'Cisco_Pending'
}];

$scope.severities = [
    {label:$scope.resource['landingpage.label.severity1'], name:'1',id:'1'}, 
    {label:$scope.resource['landingpage.label.severity2'], name: '2',id:'2'}, 
    {label:$scope.resource['landingpage.label.severity3'], name: '3',id:'3'}, 
    {label:$scope.resource['landingpage.label.severity4'], name: '4',id:'4'}
];
```

Onclick of a button or a checkbox, I have to disable some options in the dropdown. How do we do that? Can anyone suggest here. Thanks.

Comment: Please, see the link below. Does it help you? https://github.com/dotansimha/angularjs-dropdown-multiselect/issues/30